# Choosing RC values for Active LPF to match signal input impedance

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance-matching, low-pass, active-filter, time-constant

I am design a basic 1st order Active LPF with unity gain and am new to this field. How do I make sure that I choose my R and C values to match the input signal impedance or does this not matter? What other factors should I consider? Does the RC time constant matter?

[image]

Comment: you should drive this from an opamp buffer or opamp gain stage. otherwise that RC filter single-pole corner frequency will be off.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the input signal for this filter is from an instrumentation amplifier. Does the input signal still require to be driven by a buffer? If not, can I just choose my RC values based on standard components and the cutoff frequency?

Answer (score 1):

Few *pure* voltage sources are to be found in real circuits. One often considers a voltage source to be accompanied by a *source resistance* \$ R_s\$. This resistance might be found in a sensor's data sheet.

*Source resistance* might also arise from *output resistance* of a previous stage. The model of this low-pass filter then becomes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2finqlZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This stage may be part of a chain. Its output resistance at **Vout** is usually considered to be very low, thanks to the op-amp. However, at higher frequencies where op-amp gain drops off, output resistance may not be so very low.

Comment: Is this the only consideration I need to make when choosing RC values?

Comment: Depends on frequency. At very high frequencies (Above ~100MHz) there are many considerations needed. These can include impedance matching, parasitic reduction and high bandwidth parts. I do not think you are in this range, so you probably don't have to worry about any of that.

Comment: As for lower frequencies, you are mainly concerned with choosing standard part values that will not load your input heavily. Your amplifier can only supply so much current, so you don't want to try to draw more than it can provide. In this case, you want to use larger value resistors. However, you don't want to choose a value so  large that you are forced to choose a really small capacitor. A general good range is ~1kΩ - 1MΩ for resistors, and ~10nF - 10uF for caps. They're pros/cons to it all, but for most basic circuits this general advice should suffice.

Comment: Where \$R_s\$ is not well-behaved, R1 might be chosen large enough to be dominant. But a very large R1 generates Johnson noise, and DC offset (if op-amp bias current is considered).